# Importing data from JSON to DB questions

Tags: python, json, django

I want to import data that is in regular JSON format into a (SQLite) db within Django. It looks like [fixtures](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/initial-data/) is the recommended way of doing that. I'm not very clear on the steps I need take. Specifically, do I need to create a mapping of which field should go into which model (assuming my model is already defined in models.py) etc? The Django example looks like this:

```
[
   {

    "model": "myapp.person",
    "pk": 1,
    "fields": {
      "first_name": "John",
      "last_name": "Lennon"
    }   },   {
    "model": "myapp.person",
    "pk": 2,
    "fields": {
      "first_name": "Paul",
      "last_name": "McCartney"
    }
} ]
```

However my data isn't in this format. Do I need to edit the JSON file to look like this? Should I just abort and `import json` instead?

Answer (score 0):

json.loads is all that would be needed. Something like

```
as_object_list = json.loads(your_json)
```

This converts the json to a dict, from there you can can create the model by doing

YourModel.objects.create(**as_object_list)